# How to get flash contents to a C# application?

Tags: c#, html, flash

Okay, this is what I want to do:

There is a flash program on my site which allows to chat with people. People can join, there is a list that shows people in the lobby, can make private chat rooms, video chat is also possible, there is also a public chat room.

Anyone can join and start chatting. Now I want to develop a desktop application in C#
which does the same thing, but I want to interact this desktop application with the flash on my website.

I should be able to get people in the flash program to the C# application, make video chat with people from C# applications to people in the flash application and vise versa.

This also allows to chat with people on my site. I didn't develop the flash chat program myself, I bought it from someone else. This means I don't know its code, and I still have no idea where to start. If you can show me some way that would be really helpful!

Comment: Lots of help here: https://www.google.com/#q=pass+flash+content+to+c%23+application

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActiveX control Object for .net,this is a good tutorial for start([communicate betwen c# and an embeded flash-application](http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/communicate-betwen-c-and-an-embeded-flash-application/))

Comment: use Best SWF Source Code Viewer Convert SWF to FLA or FLEX precisely. Easily extracts Flash resources like images, sounds, videos, etc.download link:http://www.sothink.com/page/swf-decompiler/swf-source-code.htm